# argument of type 'int' is not iterable in my function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to resolve an issue with my code, where I am executing my function `play()` , but the argument i pass in of `--b` is an `int`, what am I doing wrong?

```
import argparse
from num2words import num2words
import subprocess

def play():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--b", default='99',type=str,help="B?")
    args = parser.parse_args() 
    for iteration in reversed(range(args.b)):
        print('Wee!')

play()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    subprocess.call(['./file.py', '10'], shell=True)
```

I am executing this via:

```
>>> import sys; import subprocess;
>>> subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'file.py', '--b', 10])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".\subprocess.py", line 480, in call
  File ".\subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
  File ".\subprocess.py", line 801, in _execute_child
  File ".\subprocess.py", line 541, in list2cmdline
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Comment: Put `10` in quotes: `"10"`

Comment: I think you have to pass it as string. So as @baldr said, try `subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'file.py', '--b', str(10)])`

Comment: @Memnon - This gives me an error of: "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"

Comment: Is the stack trace the same then?

Comment: @user700070 The subprocess.call runs on my system, are you sure the TypeError is not from your file.py?

Comment: `default=99` is not a string!

Comment: In addition to what @MKesper said, it seems you are not sure if the `b` parameter should be a string or an integer. Looking at your code, your expression `range(args.b)` tells me you really want an integer. Also, why the `subprocess.call` at the end of the script? If you run this script from the command line, it will run into an infinite loop trying to call itself.

Comment: It just write `Wee!` 99 times. I don't get any errors. Please post a complete minimal verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @skyking If you look at my answer, you will see that the example is completely fine, and the error is really there. You’re all just looking at the wrong code.

Comment: All - please see updated code. This is still throwing the error of TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable when i run: >>> subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'file.py', '--b', '10'])

Comment: @skyking The error is caused by the second code, so yes, it is posted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'file.py', '--b', 10])
```

All arguments in the argument list to `subprocess.call` (or other functions of the module) need to be string. So if you change the `10` to be a string `'10'` instead, it will work just fine:

```
subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'file.py', '--b', '10'])
```

Note that calling a Python file using `subprocess` will not give you any exception when the called file fails to execute. It’s a completely separate process which—if it fails—just produces some error output you can read from the subprocess then.

Comment: This is returning 0, any idea why?

Comment: @user700070 Because [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) returns the error code of the called application.

Comment: Why isnt it outputting the value from print?

Comment: Because that’s not what `subprocess.call` does. Please read the module documentation.